# Android get unique firebase token and authenticate with cloud functions

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a multi-player Android game, and it uses Firebase Cloud Functions.
There are some tutorials that explains how to allow only users of my application to use my cloud function (link below), but I don't want to allow all the users to use all my functions, I want to give access based on Id. How to generate unique tokens for every user, from Android (`Using Java not Kotlin`) and how to get the Id from that token in `node.js (Javascript not TypeScript)`?

The tutorial link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server

Comment: Are you registering the user in firebase?

Comment: No, the user is already signed in and has an account. I just want a way to verify which user is sending the request in my cloud function, so I can give access based on ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting Firebase Functions 1.0+, there are 2 kinds of HTTP functions that you can use for your Android app.

1. Call Functions directly. Via `functions.https.onCall`
2. Call Functions through HTTP Request. Via `functions.https.onRequest`

I recommend you to use `onCall` as your functions endpoint, and call directly by using `FirebaseFunctions`. This way, you don't need to get FirebaseUser token, as it will be automatically included when you call using `FirebaseFunctions`.

And remember, TypeScript is just superset of Javascript. I will still give examples in Node.js, but it is recommended to type your Javascript code in TypeScript.

**Example**

index.js (CloudFunctions endpoint)

```
exports.importantfunc = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   // Authentication / user information is automatically added to the request.
   if (!context.auth) {
       // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
       throw new functions.https.HttpsError('not-authorised', 
                         'The function must be called while authenticated.');
   }

   const uid = context.auth.uid;
   const email = context.auth.token.email;

   //Do whatever you want
});
```

MyFragment.java

```
//Just some snippets of code examples
private void callFunction() {
    FirebaseFunctions func = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();
    func.getHttpsCallable("importantfunc")
            .call()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<HttpsCallableResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult > task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                         //Success
                    } else {
                         //Failed
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

More information about callable function, [read here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

Comment: Thanks, it finally worked! And it's actually easier than getting and sending and verifying tokens manually.

Comment: on iOS i am unable to get it running , i am getting this error :
Error Domain=com.firebase.functions Code=9 "The function must be called while authenticated." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The function must be called while authenticated.}